# Pandas.read_excel KeyError on reading set of xlsx files

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using Anaconda shell for data analitycs
Uploding to pandas bunch of excel files (25 files)
On This files https://www.dropbox.com/s/16ea1cw6k63i16p/Newdata.zip?dl=0
I get error. Cant find the reason why and how to fix it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Twentyouts\Desktop\Newdata" )
path = os.getcwd()

files = os.listdir(path)
files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

for f in files_xlsx:
    print(f)
    loading = pd.read_excel(f, heading = 0)
    df = df.append(loading)
2016-06-20–2016-06-26.xlsx
2016-06-27–2016-07-03.xlsx
2016-07-04–2016-07-10.xlsx
2016-07-11–2016-07-17.xlsx
2016-08-01–2016-08-07.xlsx
2016-08-15–2016-08-21.xlsx
```

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-5737d4d13b9f> in <module>()
      1 df = pd.DataFrame()
----> 2 pd.read_excel('2016-08-15–2016-08-21.xlsx')

C:\Users\Twentyouts\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in read_excel(io, sheetname, header, skiprows, skip_footer, index_col, names, parse_cols, parse_dates, date_parser, na_values, thousands, convert_float, has_index_names, converters, true_values, false_values, engine, squeeze, **kwds)
    189 
    190     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 191         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    192 
    193     return io._parse_excel(

C:\Users\Twentyouts\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in __init__(self, io, **kwds)
    247             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
    248         elif isinstance(io, compat.string_types):
--> 249             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
    250         else:
    251             raise ValueError('Must explicitly set engine if not passing in'

C:\Users\Twentyouts\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    420                 formatting_info=formatting_info,
    421                 on_demand=on_demand,
--> 422                 ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
    423                 )
    424             return bk

C:\Users\Twentyouts\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py in open_workbook_2007_xml(zf, component_names, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    831         x12sheet = X12Sheet(sheet, logfile, verbosity)
    832         heading = "Sheet %r (sheetx=%d) from %r" % (sheet.name, sheetx, fname)
--> 833         x12sheet.process_stream(zflo, heading)
    834         del zflo
    835 

C:\Users\Twentyouts\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py in own_process_stream(self, stream, heading)
    546         for event, elem in ET.iterparse(stream):
    547             if elem.tag == row_tag:
--> 548                 self_do_row(elem)
    549                 elem.clear() # destroy all child elements (cells)
    550             elif elem.tag == U_SSML12 + "dimension":

C:\Users\Twentyouts\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py in do_row(self, row_elem)
    743                     else:
    744                         bad_child_tag(child_tag)
--> 745                 value = error_code_from_text[tvalue]
    746                 self.sheet.put_cell(rowx, colx, XL_CELL_ERROR, value, xf_index)
    747             elif cell_type == "inlineStr":

KeyError: None
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. `x = pd.read_excel('D:\\download\\2016-08-152016-08-21.xlsx')` - works just fine for me (Pandas v 0.19.2). What is your Pandas version?

Comment: Tried the same file. Loads perfectly with no error.
But when i load bunch of files error occurs.
I use jupiter.

Comment: In order to be able to help you we would need a __reproducible__ excel file(s)...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8gif3ivs3fjw47q/AABHR7j1x355IJHc4U2m5sqQa?dl=0 uploaded xlsx files

Comment: could you pack them into a single .ZIP file and upload that single ZIP file?

Comment: Yes, sorry.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/16ea1cw6k63i16p/Newdata.zip?dl=0

Comment: So you want to merge ALL those `xlsx` files?

Comment: Yes. After i need to do some manipulations in pandas.

Comment: It looks like those failed xlsx files are not in proper format though visibly they look exactly like the others one. I suspect somewhere in their development you changed the extension from .xls to .xlsx which is NOT the correct way to render OpenXML workbooks (Excel files 2007-2016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed as @MaxU points out, Excel files are malformed but interestingly does resolve when properly saved as an .xlsx file. Possibly, the invalid files were attempted to be upgraded from previous .xls version by simply changing the extension to .xlsx. These two file formats are not simple text files that can change extension without hazard but very different binary formats.

Consider running a COM interface using `wn32com` module to properly save the malformed files to actual OpenXML workbooks using Excel's [Workbook.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) method. Note: this solution is only compliant in Python for Windows with installed MS Excel.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import win32com.client as win32

xlsxfiles = glob.glob("C:\\Path\\To\\Workbooks\\*.xlsx")

def save_xlsx(srcfile):
    try:
        newfile = srcfile.replace('.xlsx', '_new.xlsx')
        print('Malformed file saved as {}'.format(newfile))
        xlApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(srcfile)
        wb.SaveAs(newfile, 51)                 

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)            
    finally:
        wb.Close(True); wb = None
        xlApp.Quit; xlApp = None    
    return newfile

def xl_read():    
    dfs = []
    for f in xlsxfiles:        
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(f)
        except Exception as e:            
            df = pd.read_excel(save_xlsx(f))

        print('File: {}, Shape: {}'.format(f, df.shape))
        dfs.append(df)            
    return pd.concat(dfs)

print('Final dataframe shape: {}'.format(xl_read().shape))
```

**Output** *(final dataframe of 330,257 rows and 30 columns)*

```
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-06-20–2016-06-26.xlsx, Shape: (5912, 27)
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-06-27–2016-07-03.xlsx, Shape: (5362, 27)
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-07-04–2016-07-10.xlsx, Shape: (5387, 27)
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-07-11–2016-07-17.xlsx, Shape: (5331, 28)
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-08-01–2016-08-07.xlsx, Shape: (4965, 28)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-08-15–2016-08-21_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-08-15–2016-08-21.xlsx, Shape: (5315, 27)
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-08-22–2016-08-28.xlsx, Shape: (5179, 27)
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-08-29–2016-09-04.xlsx, Shape: (5855, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-09-05–2016-09-11_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-09-05–2016-09-11.xlsx, Shape: (5838, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-09-12–2016-09-18_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-09-12–2016-09-18.xlsx, Shape: (5729, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-09-19–2016-09-25_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-09-19–2016-09-25.xlsx, Shape: (6401, 27)
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-09-26–2016-10-02.xlsx, Shape: (7018, 27)
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-09.xlsx, Shape: (23874, 27)
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-03–2016-10-09.xlsx, Shape: (6587, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-10–2016-10-12_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-10–2016-10-12.xlsx, Shape: (2883, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-10–2016-10-13_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-10–2016-10-13.xlsx, Shape: (4174, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-17–2016-10-20_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-17–2016-10-20.xlsx, Shape: (4560, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-17–2016-10-23_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-17–2016-10-23.xlsx, Shape: (7111, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-24–2016-10-27_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-24–2016-10-27.xlsx, Shape: (4921, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-24–2016-10-30_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-24–2016-10-30.xlsx, Shape: (8005, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-31–2016-11-06_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10-31–2016-11-06.xlsx, Shape: (7029, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-10.xlsx, Shape: (28098, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11-07–2016-11-13_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11-07–2016-11-13.xlsx, Shape: (7076, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11-14–2016-11-20_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11-14–2016-11-20.xlsx, Shape: (7758, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11-21_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11-21.xlsx, Shape: (1689, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11-21–2016-11-23_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11-21–2016-11-23.xlsx, Shape: (4711, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11-28–2016-12-04_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11-28–2016-12-04.xlsx, Shape: (9286, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-11.xlsx, Shape: (30505, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-12-05–2016-12-11_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-12-05–2016-12-11.xlsx, Shape: (8802, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-12-12–2016-12-18_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-12-12–2016-12-18.xlsx, Shape: (8333, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-12-16–2016-12-22_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-12-16–2016-12-22.xlsx, Shape: (8592, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-12-26–2016-12-31_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2016-12-26–2016-12-31.xlsx, Shape: (5362, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-01-01–2017-01-08_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-01-01–2017-01-08.xlsx, Shape: (4322, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-01-09–2017-01-15_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-01-09–2017-01-15.xlsx, Shape: (7608, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-01-23–2017-01-29_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-01-23–2017-01-29.xlsx, Shape: (8903, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-01-30–2017-02-05_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-01-30–2017-02-05.xlsx, Shape: (9173, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-02-13–2017-02-12_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-02-13–2017-02-12.xlsx, Shape: (9144, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-02-13–2017-02-19_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\2017-02-13–2017-02-19.xlsx, Shape: (9911, 27)
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\test.xlsx, Shape: (5315, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\Выгрузка 12-15.12_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\Выгрузка 12-15.12.xlsx, Shape: (4818, 27)
Malformed file saved as C:\Path\To\Workbooks\Выгрузка 21-27_new.xlsx
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\Выгрузка 21-27.xlsx, Shape: (8876, 27)
File: C:\Path\To\Workbooks\Выгрузка 26-29.12.xlsx, Shape: (4539, 27)
Final dataframe shape: (330257, 30)
```

---

Consider even a database engine approach using Windows' ACE Engine via `pyodbc` to query corresponding workbooks with pandas [`read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) since each share same sheet name, *TDSheet*.

```
#...same as above
import pyodbc

def sql_read():    
    dfs = [] 
    for f in xlsxfiles:                
        try:
            conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};'+\
                      'DBQ=C:\\Path\\To\\Workbooks\\{};'.format(f), autocommit=True)
            df =  pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [TDSheet$];', conn)

        except Exception as e:
            conn.close()
            conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};'+\
                      'DBQ=C:\\Path\\To\\Workbooks\\{};'.format(save_xlsx(f)), autocommit=True)
            df = pd.read_excel('SELECT * FROM [TDSheet$];', conn)
            conn.close()

        print('File: {}, Shape: {}'.format(f, df.shape))
        dfs.append(df)
```

Comment: Worked out!! Thank you.

Comment: I tried @Parfait code and it returns some error if you're not running it correctly. Must run it on empty notebook and don't change any except the directory

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some of your Excel files are malformed:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

excel_files_mask = r'D:\temp\.data\42468475\*.xlsx'

files = glob.glob(excel_files_mask)

def merge_excel_files(files, **kwargs):
    #return pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f, **kwargs) for f in files],
    #                 ignore_index=True)
    dfs = []
    for f in files:
        #print('processing: [{}]'.format(f))
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(f, **kwargs)
            dfs.append(df)
            print('parsed: [{}], shape: {}'.format(f, df.shape))
        except KeyError:
            print("ERROR: file [{}] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...".format(f))
    return pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

df = merge_excel_files(files, header=None, skiprows=1)
print(df.shape)
```

Yields:

```
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-06-20–2016-06-26.xlsx], shape: (5912, 27)
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-06-27–2016-07-03.xlsx], shape: (5362, 27)
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-07-04–2016-07-10.xlsx], shape: (5387, 27)
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-07-11–2016-07-17.xlsx], shape: (5331, 28)
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-08-01–2016-08-07.xlsx], shape: (4965, 28)
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-08-15–2016-08-21.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-08-22–2016-08-28.xlsx], shape: (5179, 27)
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-08-29–2016-09-04.xlsx], shape: (5855, 27)
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-09-05–2016-09-11.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-09-12–2016-09-18.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-09-19–2016-09-25.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-09-26–2016-10-02.xlsx], shape: (7018, 27)
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-09.xlsx], shape: (23874, 27)
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-10-03–2016-10-09.xlsx], shape: (6587, 27)
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-10-10–2016-10-12.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-10-10–2016-10-13.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-10-17–2016-10-20.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-10-17–2016-10-23.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-10-24–2016-10-27.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-10-24–2016-10-30.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-10-31–2016-11-06.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-10.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-11-07–2016-11-13.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-11-14–2016-11-20.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-11-21.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-11-21–2016-11-23.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-11-28–2016-12-04.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-11.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-12-05–2016-12-11.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-12-12–2016-12-18.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-12-16–2016-12-22.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2016-12-26–2016-12-31.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2017-01-01–2017-01-08.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2017-01-09–2017-01-15.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2017-01-23–2017-01-29.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2017-01-30–2017-02-05.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2017-02-13–2017-02-12.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\2017-02-13–2017-02-19.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\test.xlsx], shape: (5315, 27)
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\Выгрузка 12-15.12.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
ERROR: file [D:\temp\.data\42468475\Выгрузка 21-27.xlsx] couldn't be parsed! Open it in Excel and save it as (.xlsx) file ...
parsed: [D:\temp\.data\42468475\Выгрузка 26-29.12.xlsx], shape: (4539, 27)
(85324, 28)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tassos/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/home/tassos/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/home/tassos/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/home/tassos/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 37, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/home/tassos/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 138, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "/home/tassos/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 812, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    x12book.process_stream(zflo, 'Workbook')
  File "/home/tassos/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 271, in process_stream
    meth(self, elem)
  File "/home/tassos/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 380, in do_sheet
    reltype = self.relid2reltype[rid]
KeyError: ''
```

Find Out that the problem was that I had concurrently opened the file with my spreadsheet program (Libre-Spreadsheets), so as long as the file is opened from another program

```
pd.read_excel("file.xlsx","Sheet1")
```

won't run. This is another case that an Excel file is considered as malformed! Hope it helps!